# Error "PLS-00302: component 'MIN' must be declared" trying to find min/max value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im getting the error "PLS-00302: component 'MIN' must be declared" when trying to find min/max value for a distance trip. Any thoughts?

```
create or replace procedure longandshortdist (p_distance in number)
is
  cursor longshortcursor is 
    select source_town, destination_town, distance
    from distances
    where distance = p_distance;
  distance_row longshortcursor%rowtype;

begin
  for distance_row in longshortcursor
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('source town is: ' || distance_row.source_town || 'destination 
    town is: ' || distance_row.destination_town || 'shortest trip is: ' || 
    distance_row.min(distance) || 'longest trip is: ' || distance_row.max(distance));
    
  end loop;
end;
```

The error code I'm getting:

```
12/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
12/169    PLS-00302: component 'MIN' must be declared
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: You cannot use `MIN` and `MAX` like that; they are aggregation function that work inside an SQL statement (and not in PL/SQL) and you would not, typically, apply them to a single row. Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for sample data; and the expected output from your procedure so that we understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you might be a little confused with your logic here. Your procedure takes a parameter, and then uses it in the where clause: **where distance = p_distance;** so every row that comes back from that cursor will have the SAME distance.  MIN and MAX would make any sense in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

Read comments; seem to be very useful. Meanwhile, I tried to figure out what you wanted and this might be "it".

For sample data as

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2      FROM distances
  3  ORDER BY distance;

SOURCE_TOW DESTINAT   DISTANCE
---------- -------- ----------
Zagreb     Karlovac         40
Zadar      Split           120
Koprivnica Osijek          200
```

procedure doesn't accept any parameters (because, you'd fetch only rows whose distance is equal to `p_distance` (once again, see Connor's comment)) and loops through all rows in a table.

Loop itself displays all towns, but MIN and MAX distance are displayed only once - out of the loop, once you actually *calculate* their values.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE longandshortdist
  2  IS
  3     mindist  NUMBER := 1E6;
  4     maxdist  NUMBER := 0;
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR cur_r
  7        IN (SELECT source_town, destination_town, distance FROM distances)
  8     LOOP
  9        mindist := LEAST (mindist, cur_r.distance);
 10        maxdist := GREATEST (maxdist, cur_r.distance);
 11
 12        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 13              'source town is: '
 14           || cur_r.source_town
 15           || ', destination town is: '
 16           || cur_r.destination_town
 17           || ', distance is: '
 18           || cur_r.distance);
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 22        'shortest trip is: ' || mindist || ', longest trip is: ' || maxdist);
 23  END;
 24  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> EXEC longandshortdist;
source town is: Zagreb, destination town is: Karlovac, distance is: 40
source town is: Zadar, destination town is: Split, distance is: 120
source town is: Koprivnica, destination town is: Osijek, distance is: 200
shortest trip is: 40, longest trip is: 200

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `min` and `max` are aggregate functions used within a query and not inside a block.

Example:

```
SELECT max(a.f) max, min(a.f) min
FROM (
select 1 f from dual
union all
select 2 f from dual
union all
select 3 f from dual) a
```

Result:

| MAX | MIN |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

OR
I think you are trying to get the min / max of two values , if so check the links below  :
[max function greatest](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php)

[min function least](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/least.php)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tyler2P thank you for that , i will take your comment in consideration for further similar situations